# How to use the "Iterate Rasters" tool in ModelBuilder to link "Raster to Other Format (multiple)" tool to the "Extract by attributes" tool in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-conversion

I wish to link the "Raster to Other Format (multiple)" tool  to the "Extract by atttributes" tool. The "Raster to Other Format (multiple)" tool  only allows you to specify an output workspace, but the "Extract by atttributes" tool requires a specific raster to be named as input.

I am attempting to use the "Iterate Raster" tool to provide the specific raster needed as input to the Extract tool but cannot get the 2 tools to link.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are likely many ways to accomplish this.  I struggled with multiple iterators/sub model and finally decided on this method.  The input rasters are housed in a File Geodatabase.

To convert the rasters to another format I used the [Copy Raster (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000) tool which allows you to specify a desired file extension for the output raster.  This was used instead of the 'Raster To Other Format (Conversion)' script which as pointed out, uses an output workspace which cannot connect to a tool such as the 'Extract by attributes (Spatial Analyst).'

[image: Extract Raster Model]